# How to query if a value from one collection occurs in a field value of second collection as a string?

Tags: mongodb

I have another question regarding Mongo DB Queries.I already asked this question using only one collection but it seems I am completely incapable
to help myself:(.
I have 2 collections looks like this for example:

collection patients:

```
{"_id": 1,
"$firstname": 'Max',
"$lastname": 'Mustermann'},

{"_id": 2,
"$firstname": 'Marina',
"$lastname": 'Musterfrau'}
```

collection text:

```
{"_id": 123,
"$content": 'Max Mustermann leidet unter Kopfschmerzen'}, 
{"_id":456,
"$content": 'Patientin leidet unter Kopfschmerzen'}
```

And now i want to query the $content where the values of **$firstname** and **$lastname** from collection **$patients** occur in the **$content** which would only give me the collection of Max Mustermann.

Background is that i need to gather the text data from **$content** and check if there is sensible data in there like the name, the birthday or anything like this. If it does contain sensible data is there a way to anonymize those parts of the text? If not i would just leave those ones out where the query is true e.g. the $content contains sensible data.

Result should be like:

```
{"_id": 123,
"$content": 'Max Mustermann leidet unter Kopfschmerzen'}
```

Thank you very much for your help!